# Как запрашивать прямую ссылку на видео src?

Tags: php, парсер, php7

Есть такой сайт - "http://kino-2018.club/471-mstiteli-voyna-beskonechnosti.html". Они используют HLS для транслирования видео. Как можно запрашивать прямую ссылку на видео src у сайта?
Спасибо!